# Trusted sites and EDGE - viewing HTTPS sites without providing authentication

Tags: windows, group-policy, microsoft-edge

We have SSRS and tableau instances set up on our local network that are accessible without having to provide authentication in Chrome or IE11.  We've done this by adding their urls to the Trusted Sites list by GPO.

This doesn't seem to have worked for EDGE however - whenever we're accessing these sites using Edge it still asks us for login credentials.  I've looked in as many places as I can think of and I'm finally stuck.  Is there anything you guys can think of that I should be looking at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Integrated authentication options per browser perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think integrated authentication only works in the 'local intranet' zone.

Trouble is you can't manage these zones in Edge, only IE11. I hope you're not still trying to solve this problem. A lot of people are just ditching Edge and installing Chrome I believe.